# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it [not similar to others]

Tags: c#

I'm trying to learn Socket Programming, and I encountered this error while connecting to my server application.

Here's my declaration of the TcpListener in the server application:

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 5152);
```

and here's my declaration of the TcpClient in my client application:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Loopback).HostName, 5152);
```

I have read several questions like this, and I always get the same answer: Either the server application isn't listening to the port or not running at all. But I've double-checked the Resource Monitor and cmd using netstat to see if the service is listening to the port, and it is. I've also included the service in the Firewall exceptions, so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error while trying to connect to the server app.

Any ideas?

Comment: you can also provide the statistics for the given common check list like netstat, resource monitor etc...

Comment: @saravanan, what do you mean by statistics? Sorry, quite confused. Do you mean screenshots or proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Loopback).HostName` returns the host name of your machine. When you pass a host name to `TcpClient`, it will resolve it to one or more IP addresses using `Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName)`. This includes the public and link-local IP addresses of your machine (e.g., 192.168.15.4), but not the loopback address (127.0.0.1).

So your client is trying to connect to any of the non-loopback addresses of your machine, while your server is listening only on the loopback address. Thus, no connection can be established.

*Solution:* Connect to the same end point your server is listening on.

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5152);

TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(endPoint);

TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(endPoint);
```

Comment: I tried this, but I've got a problem.

I have the server and client forms at different projects, so what I did was just imported the client form to the server project, just to make things more simple.

But I have this error:

    Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I'm pretty sure I know what that means, but not sure why I'm getting it. I only followed your instructions.